xml.Unmarshal - parsing null character entity yields error: illegal character code U+0000
I know this is kinda weird thing to do, but it is part if an integration test, where I am testing whether system does not get tricked by \0, sent as URL encoded %%0. The system is indeed not tricked and echoes the value back as an XML error. But my test code fails then, trying to parse it. This is IMO valid XML:
     <Error>
        <Code>1234</Code>
        <Message>Test&#0;afterzero</Message>
     </Error>

But this code would have an error, instead of a string with \0 in it:
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type ErrorMsg struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Error"`
    Code    string   `xml:"Code"`
    Message string   `xml:"Message"`
}

func main() {

    var data = []byte(`
          <Error>
            <Code>1234</Code>
            <Message>Test&#0;afterzero</Message>
          </Error>
       `)

    b := ErrorMsg{}
    o := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &b)
    fmt.Println(o)
    fmt.Println(b)
}

See the example here: https://go.dev/play/p/1fKyuzZPUM8
Can I do something? I suppose I could just scrap this test - I did check it doesn't crash the system and it's really weird corner case, but I kinda would like to keep it.
Can I tell the XML to accept this somehow?


This is IMO valid XML

That is NOT valid XML. The &#0; character is not a valid XML character and cannot be in an XML document. Any XML parser will fail to parse.
Refer to the specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets

Character Range
[2]    Char       ::=      #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]  /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */

That character is not allowable in XML. So, you may need to find a different way to indicate what the character is if it's outside the allowable range.

So the endpoint I am testing shouldn't be returning this in the first place, right? The error is required to be valid XML document after all.

On a second read, it seems you are referring to characters allowed in the XML source code. &#0; is several characters that after parsing would yield \0. The spec seems to be talking about what is in the XML before parsing, not what XML entities are allowed. But maybe I am just reading it wrong. Can you clarify? It's odd that two endpoints that use a different serializer would both successfully serialize this if it is invalid.

Controll characters such as NULL have no place in an XML document. Whether it's a literal character or numeric entity (which will be parsed and interpreted by the XML parser as that character).

"So the endpoint I am testing shouldn't be returning this in the first place, right?" Correct. If the contract is that it sends you XML, then it shouldn't be sending non-XML.

Interesting. Like I said, I tested multiple implementations and got the same invalid XML back. It's weird that the XML builders allow this in the first place.

To better illustrate the Mads' point, let's cite the spec regarding treatment of entities (&#0; is an entity): «An entity is included when its replacement text is retrieved and processed, in place of the reference itself, as though it were part of the document at the location the reference was recognized». So basically when a conformant parser reads &#0;, and the current parse context requires processing of the entity, it should behave as if there was a byte with value 0 instead of the four bytes making up the entity's text.
